# How to filter data based on input array in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, filter

I am receiving an Input from front-end like this

```
{
"options":[
      {
          "optionId":"5ebbe0f56b197f36fc472168"
      },
      {
           "optionId":"5ebbe1aa6b197f36fc47216e"
      }
]
```

}

I want to filter data in a way such that when I filter data I should receive an array of object which contains both these two id's

I have structure from where I need to find this

```
"answersArray" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ede62f6a6979e5128bb89ba"),
        "questionId" : ObjectId("5ebbe00e6b197f36fc472161"),
        "answerId" : ObjectId("5ebbe00e6b197f36fc472162")
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ede62f6a6979e5128bb89b9"),
        "questionId" : ObjectId("5ebbe0f56b197f36fc472168"),
        "answerId" : ObjectId("5ebbe0f56b197f36fc472169")
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ede62f6a6979e5128bb89b8"),
        "questionId" : ObjectId("5ebbe1aa6b197f36fc47216e"),
        "answerId" : ObjectId("5ebbe1aa6b197f36fc47216f")
    }
],

"answersArray" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ede620ea6979e5128bb89b5"),
        "questionId" : ObjectId("5ebbd4e76b197f36fc47211e"),
        "answerId" : ObjectId("5ebbd4e76b197f36fc47211f")
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ede620ea6979e5128bb89b4"),
        "questionId" : ObjectId("5ebbd5516b197f36fc472120"),
        "answerId" : ObjectId("5ebbd5516b197f36fc472121")
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ede62f6a6979e5128bb89b8"),
        "questionId" : ObjectId("5ebbe1aa6b197f36fc47216e"),
        "answerId" : ObjectId("5ebbe1aa6b197f36fc47216f")
    },
```

]

I am expecting this answer

```
 "answersArray" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ede62f6a6979e5128bb89ba"),
        "questionId" : ObjectId("5ebbe00e6b197f36fc472161"),
        "answerId" : ObjectId("5ebbe00e6b197f36fc472162")
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ede62f6a6979e5128bb89b9"),
        "questionId" : ObjectId("5ebbe0f56b197f36fc472168"),
        "answerId" : ObjectId("5ebbe0f56b197f36fc472169")
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ede62f6a6979e5128bb89b8"),
        "questionId" : ObjectId("5ebbe1aa6b197f36fc47216e"),
        "answerId" : ObjectId("5ebbe1aa6b197f36fc47216f")
    }
],
```

How can I filter this any suggestions?

Comment: Use the `$in` operator : `.find({ _id : { $in : ["5ebbe0f56b197f36fc472168",  "5ebbe1aa6b197f36fc47216e"]}})`

Comment: Thanks for the response but I have changed my question a little bit when using $in it's returning both the documents as second document is also having a id from input array but I want it should return only one document which  is the first one contains both the id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/).

```
db.collection.findOne(
    {
        "answersArray.questionId": {$all: options.map(id => ObjectId(id))}
    }
);
```